# Spring Autowiring in Validator for Dropwizard

Tags: java, spring, validation, jersey, dropwizard

I'm using the Validator API to validate my Dropwizard resources.

At this point I need to create a custom ConstraintValidator -- but my validator must be able to connect to a database.

In order to handle this, I am using @Autowire inside my custom ConstraintValidator to provide my configured beans (the database).

```
public class CustomValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CustomAnnotation, String> {

    @Autowired private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void initialize(final CustomAnnotation customAnnotation) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(final Optional<String> value, final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        applicationContext.getApplicationName();
        return true;
    }
}
```

In order to get autowiring to work with the validator, I believe I have to use 'LocalValidatorFactoryBean'.

I've configured mine as such:-

```
final LocalValidatorFactoryBean factory = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
factory.setApplicationContext(applicationContext); // preconfigured with my beans
factory.afterPropertiesSet(); // seems to perform the setup of the ConstraintValidatorFactory with applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory()
```

Dropwizard comes with a validator pre-configured in the Environment object.

So, to ensure that Dropwizard uses the Spring configured validator with injection, I've set the environment with the LocalValidatorFactoryBean like so:-

```
environment.setValidator(factory);
```

However, rather frustratingly my @Autowired private ApplicationContext applicationContext from my CustomValidator still appears to be null.

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong here or if there is an easier way?

**Edit** A bit more info on how it was done.

Set this up in my application:-

```
final ValidatorFactory constraintValidatorFactory = // custom validator factory
final ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
jerseyEnvironment.register(new ValidationConfigurationContextResolver(constraintValidatorFactory, factory));
```

Then used this class to replace the desired validator:-

```
public class ValidationConfigurationContextResolver implements ContextResolver<ValidationConfig> {

   private final ConstraintValidatorFactory constraintValidatorFactory;
   private final ValidatorFactory factory;

   public ValidationConfigurationContextResolver(final ConstraintValidatorFactory constraintValidatorFactory,final ValidatorFactory    factory) {
       this.constraintValidatorFactory = constraintValidatorFactory;
       this.factory = factory;
   }

   @Override
   public ValidationConfig getContext(final Class<?> type) {
       final ValidationConfig config = new ValidationConfig();
       config.messageInterpolator(factory.getMessageInterpolator());
       config.constraintValidatorFactory(constraintValidatorFactory); // custom constraint validator factory
       config.parameterNameProvider(factory.getParameterNameProvider());
       config.traversableResolver(factory.getTraversableResolver());
       return config;
   }
```

}

Comment: For those wondering, i've solved this.

environment.setValidator() doesn't really do anything for jersey.

The correct thing to do is to use:-

 CustomResolver resolver = // something which implements ContextResolver<ValidationConfig>;
    jersey.register(resolver);

Comment: Any chance you can share a piece of sample code for doing this? Running into a similar problem. Does implementing the custom ContextResolver augment or replace the existing Validator configured by Dropwizard? Ideally I'd like it to just add onto the existing one rather than outright replace it.

Comment: I've updated to add a little more context for you :)